# pusher api: how can I check if the connection is established?

Tags: javascript, pusher

I'm using the pusher interface, and I would like to write a fallback for environments where the pusher service is unavailable. I can't find a way to check if the pusher subscription is ok.

I tried this

```
$scope.channel.bind('pusher:error', function() {
        console.log("pusher:error");
    });
```

and also pusher:subscription_error but it does nothing.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's important to highlight the difference between **connection** and **subscription**.

- A **connection** is a persistent connection to Pusher over which all communication takes place.
- A **subscription** is a request for data. In Pusher these are represented by **channels**. Subscriptions and associated data use the established connection and multiple subscriptions are multiplexed over a single connection.

To determine if the Pusher service is reachable or not you should check the connection state.

*However, if you ever see this I'd also recommend contacting [Pusher support](https://pusher.com/support) since this shouldn't happen.*

### Detecting & Querying Connection State

It's possible to detect connection state by binding to events on the connection object.

```
pusher.connection.bind('state_change', function(states) {
  var prevState = states.previous;
  var currState = states.current;
});
```

You can additional get the state right now.

```
var currentState = pusher.connection.state;
```

Full documentation on this can be found here:
https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_connect#connection-states

The example in the questions appears to use Angular so you'll need to get reference to the `connection` object from the `$scope`. If you're using [pusher-angular](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-angular) then the API should be the same as the normal Pusher library.

### Subscription Status

You can bind to two events to determine the result of a subscription:

- `pusher:subscription_succeeded`
- `pusher:subscription_error`

The code to use these looks as follows:

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');

channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function() {
  // Yipee!!
});

channel.bind('pusher:subscription_error', function() {
  // Oh nooooos!
});
```

Documentation on the success event can be found here:
https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_events#subscription_succeeded

Docs on the error event can be found here:
https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_events#subscription_error